# Сalling the view animation by button tap from outside

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

Tell me please how can i move my "SecondCardUIView" when i tap button on "FirstCardUIView" (ViewAnimator.pageController(view: self) - animation that moves view)

Here is the view controllet that contains my views:

```
class WelcomViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "UXCrowd green")
            
    let firstCardView = FirstCardUIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,
                                                      y: 137,
                                                      width: self.view.frame.size.width,
                                                      height: self.view.frame.size.height - 137))
    let secondCardView = SecondCardUIView(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width,
                                                        y: 137,
                                                        width: self.view.frame.size.width,
                                                        height: self.view.frame.size.height - 137))
    
    self.view.addSubview(firstCardView)
    self.view.addSubview(secondCardView)
    }
}
```

First card that have button that must move both "cards" on tap (FirstCardUIView, SecondCardUIView)

```
class FirstCardUIView: UIView {
    
    private let button: CustomUIButton = {
        let button = CustomUIButton()
        
        return button
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.backgroundColor = .white
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 30
        self.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        addButton()
    }
    
    private func addButton() {
        let width: Double = 225
        let height: Double = 50
        let x: Double = Double(self.bounds.midX) - (width / 2)
        let y: Double = Double(self.bounds.maxY) - (height + 54)
        
        button.frame = CGRect(x: x,
                              y: y,
                              width: width,
                              height: height)
        button.setTitle("Далее", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        self.addSubview(button)
    }
    
    @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
        ViewAnimator.pageController(view: self)
    }
}
```

Second card that must to move when i tap button on first card (FirstCardUIView)

```
class SecondCardUIView: UIView {
    
    private let button: CustomUIButton = {
        let button = CustomUIButton()
        
        return button
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.backgroundColor = .white
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 30
        self.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        addButton()
    }
    
    private func addButton() {
        let width: Double = 225
        let height: Double = 50
        let x: Double = Double(self.bounds.midX) - (width / 2)
        let y: Double = Double(self.bounds.maxY) - (height + 54)
        
        button.frame = CGRect(x: x,
                              y: y,
                              width: width,
                              height: height)
        button.setTitle("Далее", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        self.addSubview(button)
    }
    
    @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
        ViewAnimator.pageController(view: self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There a couple of ways how your `FirstCardUIView` and `SecondCardUIView` can interact.

- **NSNotificationCenter** registers key to observe, sender sends same key with or without object message, registering receiver acts when notification arrives. (WelcomViewController is not involved then, but reusing the UIViews in other projects involves knowledge of this key)
- **KVO** programming observing a property of FirstCardUIView in your WelcomViewController and act accordingly to change SecondCardUIView. KVO has the advantage that you can place methods that invoke directly before or directly after a property changes and several other possible changing patterns of the property.
- defining a **Protocol** and expose a **delegate id** following the protocol.
  Powerful features possible with this pattern but a bit more coding and reusing the code depends on the availability of this protocol where its needed (headers, imports). Advantage here is that a Class can use features of another Class meant for use with objects that follow the same Protocol. So when FirstCardUIView knows of a delegate that is given by SecondCardUIView it could act when FirstCardUIView invokes the delegates `<Protocol>` method.
- make it even easier:

Your FirstCardUIView and SecondCardUIView could be **subclass of UIControl**.
As UIControl inherits from UIView it works as is plus you are able to **set actions on targets**.

the example below shows both, use of UIControl actions & targets and/or using Notifications. Only one of the solutions is needed.

```
import UIKit


extension Notification.Name {
     static let secondCardNotification = Notification.Name("secondCardNotification")
}

@objc // only needed when exposing to Objective-C
class WelcomViewController: UIViewController {

    var firstCardControl : FirstCardUIControl! //UIControl
    var secondCardControl : SecondCardUIControl! //UIControl
        
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "UXCrowd green")
        
        firstCardControl = FirstCardUIControl(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 137, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height - 137))
        secondCardControl = SecondCardUIControl(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width, y: 137, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height - 137))
        
        self.view.addSubview(firstCardControl)
        self.view.addSubview(secondCardControl)
        
        //secondCardControls button triggers firstCardControls buttonAction
        secondCardControl.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(actOnBehalfOfSecondCardViewsButton), for: .touchDown)
    }
    
    @objc func actOnBehalfOfSecondCardViewsButton() {
        firstCardControl.buttonAction(sender: nil)
    }

}

class FirstCardUIControl: UIControl {
    
    //private let button: CustomUIButton = {
    //    let button = CustomUIButton()
    //
    //    return button
    //}()
    let button: UIButton! = UIButton()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.backgroundColor = .white
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 30
        self.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(receivedNotification(notification:)), name: .secondCardNotification, object: nil)
    }
    
    @objc func receivedNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
         //ViewAnimator.pageController(view: self)
        print("notification ", notification.name.rawValue, " received")
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        //fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        super.init(coder:coder)
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        addButton()
    }
    
    private func addButton() {
        let width: Double = 225
        let height: Double = 50
        let x: Double = Double(self.bounds.midX) - (width / 2)
        let y: Double = Double(self.bounds.maxY) - (height + 54)
        
        button.frame = CGRect(x: x,
                              y: y,
                              width: width,
                              height: height)
        button.setTitle("Далее", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        self.addSubview(button)
    }
    
    @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
        //self.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
        //ViewAnimator.pageController(view: self)
    }
}


class SecondCardUIControl: UIControl {
    
    //private let button: CustomUIButton = {
    //    let button = CustomUIButton()
    //
    //    return button
    //}()
    let button: UIButton! = UIButton()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.backgroundColor = .white
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 30
        self.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        //fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        super.init(coder:coder)
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        addButton()
    }
    
    private func addButton() {
        let width: Double = 225
        let height: Double = 50
        let x: Double = Double(self.bounds.midX) - (width / 2)
        let y: Double = Double(self.bounds.maxY) - (height + 54)
        
        button.frame = CGRect(x: x,
                              y: y,
                              width: width,
                              height: height)
        button.setTitle("Далее", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        self.addSubview(button)
    }
    
    @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
        //ViewAnimator.pageController(view: self)
        NSLog("SecondCardUIView:buttonAction: invoked")
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .secondCardNotification, object: nil)
        NSLog("notification %@ posted", Notification.Name.secondCardNotification.rawValue )
    }
}
```

Comment: feel free to edit the example, i am more objC dude last weeks.